# Flutter themeData font not reflecting

Tags: flutter

Plarform -

```
→ flutter --version
Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel dev • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 022b333a08 (12 days ago) • 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
Engine • revision 07c1eed46b
Tools • Dart 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)
```

SRC -

```
class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: _lightPrimaryColor,
    .........
    fontFamily: 'Texturina',
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      caption: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black87,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Pubspec.yaml -

```
fonts:
    - family: Texturina
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Texturina/Texturina-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Texturina/Texturina-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Texturina/Texturina-Black.ttf
```

Nothing changes if I change `fontFamily` to anything.

Comment: Is the indentation of `fonts` correct? And did you try it without separate `AppTheme` class?

Comment: Probably yes. It's under `flutter`. Also, it should give an indentation error in that case. Yes, I tried it into a Text widget directly but no luck.

Comment: I think capital letters in asset folders are not allowed, so you need to rename folder 'Texturina' to 'texturina'

Comment: @someuser - That's exactly the issue. Renaming folder 'Texturina' to 'texturina' worked well. Weird issue though, must be included in documents. It would be great if you can post this as an answer.